opening an office sharepoint link in the desktop application
I often receive links to sharepoint files, which look like this:
https://myCo.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/myFolder/Shared%20Documents/myPresentationFile.pptx?d=somestring&csf=1&web=1&e=bxsaTa
I typically save them in webloc files, so I can open the shared version (and not a copy on my machine). However, double clicking on the webloc file will open the web version of the application (Microsoft Word, Excel etc) and not the desktop application. Importantly, the exact same link, when present in Microsoft Outlook, Teams etc. will open in the desktop application, as it is possible in those applications to set the default method to open links (browser vs. desktop).
In summary, my question is: is it possible to open a Microsoft Sharepoint link, saved in a webloc file, directly in the desktop application and not in the web application?

That'd be nice, but macOS doesn't know in advance what kind of document is linked so it can't choose the right app. Outlook and Teams are surely doing quite some work in the background: connecting to SharePoint with your Office credentials, checking the document type, downloading the file to a temporary folder and launching the appropriate app. It could be possible to script it with Shortcuts, though.

thank you @jaume! I am now trying to open the doc in the browser with AppleScript, and then inject Javascript to simulate clicking on "Open in Desktop" but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to do that ...(Sharepoint pages are complex, for me at least). I will keep trying...
